# Can't login to Costco.com with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping, session-cookies

I'm working on a online purchase bot for costco.com and I've run into a blocker. Upon providing correct username and password combination on the login page and clicking "login", a bot don't login. This only occurs when running through browser automation.
Especially  If I run manually chrome and manually  enter the user\pwd and login will succeed.
After I signout costco.com and turn off chrome, In this case when again I run bot in 1-2 minutes, bot login costco.
Just wondering if there's a workaround for this issue. Here is my code thus far:

```
import unittest
import pickle
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

userdata_path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile3"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir={}".format(userdata_path))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://costco.com/")
time.sleep(5)
signin = driver.find_element(By.ID, "header_sign_in")
signin.click()
time.sleep(5)

useremail = <my email>
userpassword = <my password>

username = driver.find_element(By.ID, "signInName")
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "next")
username.send_keys(useremail)
password.send_keys(userpassword)

login.click()
```

I have one issue and wait solountion

Comment: I can't test this since I don't have an account, but I noticed that your snippet goes to https://costco.com/ main page and doesn't include any lines to click *"Sign In / Register"* to go to the login page...anyway, are there any errors raised? did you observe the automated window to make sure all the steps are being executed? Have you tried `password.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` instead of *`login.click()`*?

Comment: I have delete it for underesting. So I again have just added code part.

Comment: (I thought it might be so, but I wanted to mention it just in case) did you check for the other points I asked about?

Comment: I have checked all step. In example, bot click correctly login button too. I think cookie expire issue.